# Node.js lambda function makes repeated http calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

```
const https = require('https')

exports.handler = async(event) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const parsedEvent = event

        const data = JSON.stringify(parsedEvent.data)

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };

        const endpoint = process.env.API_URL + '/' + parsedEvent.service

        const req = https.request(endpoint, options, (res) => {
            console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
            console.log('headers:', res.headers);

            res.on('finish', () => {
                return resolve({
                    statusCode: res.statusCode
                })
            })
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            return reject(e)
        });

        req.write(data)
        req.end()
    })
};
```

That's my lambda function and when I test it with the following `data`:

```
{
  "service": "transcription/check",
  "data": {
    "ConversationId": 1
  }
}
```

it makes an HTTP call as expected, except it repeatedly makes HTTP calls until it times out. Somehow, the lambda function doesn't know to end. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to handle the `data` event.

Adding:

```
res.on('data', () => {return})
```

helped